# How to display images using php when images in folder / DB

Tags: php, html

I have a DB on my localhost with a table that contains images that belong to various categories (image_category). The images are contained in a folder `i.e.: /gallery/xxxIMAGESxxx` one step higher from where I am keeping the `php` file with the `hmtl` code inside for display on a users screen.

Right now the only problem I face is that when I want to display the images on my website, they do not display. Instead I only get the Title of the image and the description which also comes from the DB.

In the style section of my anchor tag i included

```
background-image: url(gallery/'.$row["imgFullNameGallery"].')">
```

where the image should display.

I think this has to do with `Base64` encoding but I cannot point out where and how I should code this / set the syntax. If this is the problem.

Help would be much appreciated. Thx in advance.

```
//this is the php code with the call to the table with the images

<div class="display_CNC_Machining_images">
    <?php
    include_once 'includes/dbh.inc.php';

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM gallery WHERE image_category = 'CNC_Machinery'";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql)) {
      echo 'SQL statement failed!';
    } else {
      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
      $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {


//what's echoed out by the database

        echo '  <a class="images" style="background-repeat:no-repeat; background-image: url(gallery/'.$row["imgFullNameGallery"].')">
                <div class="color-overlay">
                <h3>'.$row["titleGallery"].'</h3>
                <p>'.$row["descGallery"].'</p>
                </div>
                </a>';
      }
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Expected result:

Image from DB / localfolder is displayed together with image title and image description from DB.

Actual result:

Only image title and image description from DB is displayed.

[Database with images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpEkN.png)

[displayed on my screen at the moment, no imgs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9NGD.png)

Comment: Have you checked the generated HTML code ? does the referenced file exist in `gallery/` ?

Comment: Please see comment bellow from Jelle Botman.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this:

```
echo '<a class="images" style="background-repeat:no-repeat; background-image: url(gallery/'.$row["imgFullNameGallery"].')">
<div class="color-overlay">
<h3>'.$row["titleGallery"].'</h3>
<p>'.$row["descGallery"].'</p>
</div>
</a>';
```

Do this:

```
$image = $row["imgFullNameGallery"];
echo '<a class="images" style="background-repeat:no-repeat; background-image: url(gallery/'.$image.')">
<div class="color-overlay">
<h3>'.$row["titleGallery"].'</h3>
<p>'.$row["descGallery"].'</p>
</div>
</a>';
```

Placing your `$row["imgFullNameGallery"]` into an apart variable will prevent conflicts.
The double quotes will get in conflict with the quotes from your style.
This should show the image.
Also check if your image exists in your folder.

Comment: I think there is another problem with the CSS. It worked in my main file where I keep the entire code. Although I don't see a reason why the image shouldn't display here. I will close this ticket and thx you for th effort.

Comment: You can show me your full css code so I can help, Im happy to help